# Adjective placed before a noun but adjectival complement after it

Tags: adjectives, word-order, complements

Page 14 of Practical English Usage reads

> In some cases an adjective can be put before a noun and its complement
> after it. This happens with *different, similar, the same, next, last,
> first, second* etc; comparatives and superlatives; and a few other
> adjectives like *difficult* and *easy*
>
> *The best mother in the world*

Why are *difficult/easy* dealt with as being different form *different/similar*?

Secondly, what other arrangement of words would be grammatical for superlatives, as in *The best mother in the world* ?

Comment: Calling these "adjective complements" is misleading. There's more going on here than an adjective. _Difficult_ and _easy_, for instance, govern _Tough_-Movement; all the other adjectives you mention are comparatives semantically and therefore require a baseline presupposition, often expressed as a clause. Comparative (and equative and superlative) constructions have some of the most complex syntax in English.

Comment: _She's a difficult person to deal with_ is different in form from _It's a different colour to mine._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the examples given are _a different life from this one_ and _a difficut problem to solve_

Comment: My pair was chosen to have more similar surface structure, contrasting infinitive-marker-particle-_to_ and preposition-_to_. 'To' sounds a bit awkward in place of 'from' in Swan's PP example.

Comment: I don't see why the website says that only a few adjective can have a complement; it seems to me that lots of adjectives can take one: *a strange thing to find on your doorstep*, *a peaceful place to live*, *a bad time to talk.*

Comment: ... A day on which it is good to die hard?